# How can I use "0pt plus 1fil + \baselineskip" as a length?

Tags: spacing, sectioning, koma-script, lengths, vertical-spacing

I'm trying to declare a new section command in KOMA-Script which is formatted exactly like `part`.

According to the user guide the default for `beforeskip` is `0pt plus 1fil + \baselineskip`. Unfortunately one can't just declare `beforeskip=0pt plus 1fil + \baselineskip` or `beforeskip=0pt plus \dimexpr 1fil + \baselineskip\relax`. It seems that this doesn't expand to a length.

Minimal example:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\DeclareNewSectionCommand[%
    beforeskip=0pt plus \dimexpr 1fil + \baselineskip\relax,% doesn't work: "unknown option value"
    afterskip=0pt plus 1fil,%
    style=part,%
    tocstyle=part,%
    level=-1,%
    tocindent=0em,%
    tocnumwidth=1.2em%
]{specialpart}

\begin{document}
\part{Part One}
\specialpart{Part Two}
\end{document}
```

Comment: to use an etex expression you would need `\glueexpr` not `\dimexpr` as the latter is for fixed lengths but it isn't needed here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`1\baselineskip` is a dimen not a skip so you can do

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\DeclareNewSectionCommand[%
    beforeskip=1\baselineskip plus 1fil,
    afterskip=0pt plus 1fil,%
    style=part,%
    tocstyle=part,%
    level=-1,%
    tocindent=0em,%
    tocnumwidth=1.2em%
]{specialpart}

\begin{document}

\part{Part One}
\specialpart{Part Two}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Is there no difference between `+` and `plus`?

Comment: @keth-tex classic tex has no `+`  and in an etex expresion `+` is addition, like `\advance`, `plus` isn't addition at all it is the specification of the stretch component of a glue.

Comment: @keth-tex that is `5pt plus 2pt` is not `7pt`  it is glue with natural length 5pt that can stretch a further 2pt.  but the etex expression `\dimexpr 5pt + 2pt` is the fixed length, 7pt.

Comment: That is what I thought. That `+` is addition and `plus` a possible stretch. Yet, how then is `1\baselineskip plus 1fil` the same as `0pt plus 1fil + \baselineskip`?

Comment: @keth-tex same way 1+2 is same as 3, I did the addition in my head. addition of glue adds the three components separately \baselineskip is (always in any sensible document) a fixed length, so the fixed component is 0pt+\baselineskip, the stretch component is 1fil plus 0  and the shrink component is 0 + 0.

Comment: @keth-tex but if you prefer you could use `\glueexpr 0pt plus 1fil + \baselineskip\relax`, it just seems unnecessarily complicated.

Comment: Ah okay. I see. (I thought that `\baselineskip` was part of the stretch... - So it's only the first term after `plus` or `minus` which defines the stretch?)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/109167/discussion-between-david-carlisle-and-keth-tex).